# Did Anthony Trollope's Barsetshire inspire the Archers' Borsetshire?

Tags: inspiration, setting, anthony-trollope, chronicles-of-barsetshire

[Barsetshire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barsetshire) is a fictional county of England, created by Anthony Trollope for his [*Chronicles of Barsetshire*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronicles_of_Barsetshire) series published in the mid-19th century. The county town is the equally fictional Barchester.

[Borsetshire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsetshire) is a fictional county of England, created for the extremely long-running and popular BBC radio soap [*The Archers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Archers) running from 1951 to the present day. The county town is the equally fictional Borchester.

It seems that surely the Archers' county name must have been based on Trollope's, but **is this definitively confirmed**? A [website about Anthony Trollope](https://web.archive.org/web/20150126063328/http://www.anthonytrollope.com/abouttrollope/) made this claim as one of their "Top Five Did You Know?", but this doesn't seem very reliable without a proper source or reference.

Comment: Oxfordreference.com says Borsetshire is an alteration of Barsetshire, but doesn’t source the assertion.